# PHP: Encode decode point in url $_GET urldecode

Tags: php, url, urldecode

I have:
http://www.example.com/index.php?amount=15%252E8

In index.php:

```
    $test = $_GET['amount'];
    echo $test; 

    // Output: 15%2E8
```

But I don't need **15%2E8**, I need **15.8**

```
    $test = $_GET['amount'];
    $test = urldecode($test);
    echo $test; 
    
    //Output: 15.8
```

But in https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php they warn:

> Warning:  The superglobals $_GET and $_REQUEST are already decoded.
> Using urldecode() on an element in $_GET or $_REQUEST could have
> unexpected and dangerous results.

Why **$_GET['amount']** does not get **15.8** ?!

Comment: What is the value that you send in 'amount'

Comment: You're url example shows 15%252E8 but your Output example shows 15%2E8. Is this a typo or is it really dropping off the '25' in the middle?

Answer (score 4):

`15%252E8` is the URL encoded version of "15%2E8".
`15%2E8` is the URL encoded version of "15.8".
If you want "15.8", you should be sending `15%2E8` in the URL.

I.e. you're URL-encoding one time too many somewhere.